Is the finite/countable union of topological Markov shifts a topological Markov shift?
A topological Markov shift (TMS), or countable state shift of finite type (SFT), is a shift space $X$ over a countably infinite alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ defined by a transition matrix $T=(t_{ij})_{\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}}$:
$$X=\{\cdots x_{-1}x_0x_1\cdots:t_{x_ix_{i+1}}=1\forall i\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$
I've been wondering if the union of TMSs is again a TMS, and realized that I can't even answer this question in the case that the alphabet is finite (though I found a reference saying that, indeed, the finite union of SFTs is a SFT). Here's what I've tried:

Given two TMSs $X$ and $Y$ generated by transition matrices $T$ and $S$ respectively, I tried to see if I could construct a matrix $R$ describing $X\cup Y$. One idea I had was letting $r_{ij}=\max\{t_{ij},s_{ij}\}$ but this doesn't work because it mixes the languages of $X$ and $Y$ together when all I want to do is mix their points together.

In the case of shift spaces over finite alphabets, one can prove that $X$ is an SFT iff its forbidden word set is finite. I wondered if I could do something similar for TMSs. Obviously, I can't assume finiteness, because the alphabet is infinite, and I also can't assume boundedness of the length of forbidden words, since $\{0\}$ and $\{0,00,\dots\}$ generate the same TMS, but maybe I could define a "minimal" forbidden word set as follows: define $\mathcal{F}_\text{max}=\mathcal{A}^\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathcal{L}(X)$ to be the "maximal" forbidden word set of $X$ and then let
$$\mathcal{F}_\text{min}=\{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_\text{max}:\text{no subword of }\omega\text{ occurs in }\mathcal{F}_\text{max}\}.$$
I haven't made much headway with this, but let me know if you think it's promising.


Is there a simpler approach I've overlooked? Or, is there a "better" way to define the union of two TMSs? Any help would be much appreciated.

I think of the transition matrix as being the adjacency matrix of a digraph.  Can't you then just take the disjoint union of the digraphs?  So this would be the direct sum of the two matrices.

In the standard symbolic dynamics context, the union of two full shifts is proper sofic if the alphabets intersect but neither contains the other.

(In particular, the answer to this question is no.)

@BenjaminSteinberg The issue is that in the countable state setting, every shift space can be represented as a walk on a digraph (per Theorem 6.1 here).

Maybe you should clarify your question, certainly with your definition when the alphabet is finite, a TMS will just be a vertex shift, and see my comments above.

I see. Your union is also not necessarily disjoint.

@VilleSalo What do you mean by proper sofic?

"one can prove that X
is an SFT iff its forbidden word set is finite" I imagine you mean, any infinite set of forbidden patterns has a finite subset that already defines the SFT

Proper sofic is sofic but not of finite type

"though I found a reference saying that, indeed, the finite union of SFTs is a SFT" this is true for disjoint unions (even if not necessarily alphabet disjoint), but it is false without that assumption in the finite alphabet case

@VilleSalo Ah yes, I meant that, in the finite state setting, X is an SFT iff there exists a finite forbidden word set F such that X=X_F. This is how Lind and Marcus define SFTs (Definition 2.1.1). Is it true that the disjoint union of TMSs is a TMS?

With your definition, it's true for alphabet disjoint TMS. But not in general, e.g. union of {..01010..} and {...0202020...} is not directly definable by a matrix

If you allow top. conjugacy, I may not know all the subtleties in the infinite alphabet case, but I suspect the answers are the same (for finite unions)

@VilleSalo I see, good to know. It seems, then, for the case countable of countable unions, that if I have a countable set of TMSs $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ all over $\mathcal{A}$, I can make the alphabets disjoint (so, $(\mathcal{A}i){i\in\mathbb{N}}$), and then the union of all those alphabets is a new, still countable alphabet, so the resulting disjoint union is still a TMS. Is there any issue with this?

With your definition of TMS as just sets of paths of vertices in a graph, I don't see any. But there are compactness issues to worry about in some settings.
